# How to do a 3D revolution plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose you have a 2D curve, given by e.g.:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
t = numpy.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
z = -t**2
pylab.plot(t, z)
```

which produces

[image: http://i.imgur.com/feQzk.png]

I would like to perform a revolution to achieve a 3d plot (see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html). Plotting a 3d surface is not the problem, but it does not produce the result I'm expecting:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ljXHQ.png]

How can I perform a rotation of this blue curve in the 3d plot ?

Comment: Are you asking why the blue curve is in front of the 3D surface? Matplotlib doesn't have "true" 3D plotting, so it doesn't handle occlusion of objects behind other objects, etc. If you want full 3D plotting, you'll need to use `mayavi` or something similar.  (Mayavi's `mlab` interface is very easy to get started with: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html )

Comment: No, that is not the question. I added the blue curve together with the 3D surface to better specify what I want. The 3D surface is what I can  get, but I want to perform a revolution with the blue curve to obtain a surface that I don't know how to get. The kind of the surfaces I wanna get are shown in the RevolutionPlot3D.html link.

Comment: I suspect your problem is at least partially axis limits.  In `matplotlib` you are getting a plot of all the z-values in a given x-y foot print, the mathematica examples pick a z-cut off and then makes the x-y footprint big enough to capture all of the points with z<z_cutoff (and doesn't plot data for points in the box that have z>z_cut).

Comment: Your comment makes sense, tcaswell. Is there some easy way to simulate this with matplotlib ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plot on your figure seems to use cartesian grid. There is some examples on the matplotlib website of 3D cylindrical functions like Z = f(R) (here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html).
Is that what you looking for ?
Below is what I get with your function Z = -R**2 :[image: Plot of Z = -R**2 function]

And to add cut off to your function, use the following example:
(matplotlib 1.2.0 required)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = -(abs(X) + abs(Y))

## 1) Initial surface
# Flatten mesh arrays, necessary for plot_trisurf function
X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()
Z = Z.flatten()

# Plot initial 3D surface with triangles (more flexible than quad)
#surfi = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)

## 2) Cut off
# Get desired values indexes
cut_idx = np.where(Z > -5)

# Apply the "cut off"
Xc = X[cut_idx]
Yc = Y[cut_idx]
Zc = Z[cut_idx]

# Plot the new surface (it would be impossible with quad grid)
surfc = ax.plot_trisurf(Xc, Yc, Zc, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)

# You can force limit if you want to compare both graphs...
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-5,5)
ax.set_zlim(-10,0)

plt.show()
```

Result for surfi:

[image: surfi]

and surfc:

[image: surfc]

Comment: That looks promising. How would I plot z = max(abs(xi), abs(yi)), i.e. the L1 norm ?

Comment: Hum.. If you want to plot L1 norm with x and y, it's no more a revolution plot...
Anyway, you can use the function numpy.where() for example, like this:
Z = np.where(abs(X)>abs(Y), X, Y )
You can use another matplotlib example like this [one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html).
More generally, all matplotlib 3D examples are [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d).

Comment: I have seen these examples before. I'm not sure why you consider a L1 norm cannot be represented in 3D by a revolution. Let us restrict it to some domain as [-1, 1], that certainly gives a 2D curve. Why can't I perform a revolution ?

Comment: How do you get your 2D curve, what's its equation ? I think you need to fix either x or y in your formula z = max(abs(x), abs(y)) to have only one dimension and draw a curve.

Comment: Restrict the domain of x to [-n, n], for example. In 1D we get the boring f(x) = y = abs(x). To get a concave down curve as in the earlier example we could consider f(x) = -abs(x). In 2D we can restrict both x and y to [-n, n], for example. So f(x, y) = z = -(abs(x) + abs(y)). If we instead perform z = -max(abs(x), abs(y)) then we are working with the L-infinity norm.

Comment: Thinking about this again I believe I see the problem you mention. The 1D function gives a 2D representation which corresponds to the L-infity norm in 3D. But the 2D function does not produce a single unique curve, so in that sense we cannot perform a revolution with it. After all I'm after an answer that combines yours with tcaswell's comment; I guess this was not clear at all with the given example, and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your picture. Indeed, your 3D surface could't be a simple revolution. Do you still need help to plot something else or  is the problem solved ? If so, glad you've got what you want :)

Comment: I would like achieve a result that follows the comment by tcaswell.

Comment: Ok I see. So if we speak with input and output: you would like to specify Zmin and Zmax, and get all X and Y giving a norm in the Z interval ?

Comment: The norm was an example to illustrate the issue, but we can keep on it if that helps. Suppose you have that "L1 surface" and the Z ticks on it are 0, -1, -2. The plane that cuts through Z = -2 contains only a few points (4) from the border of surface, while the plane that cuts Z = -1 contains every point in the surface's border.

How can the surface be plotted in an interval [Zmin, Zmax] such that any plane as earlier contains every point in the surface's border ?

Comment: So you actually would like to solve the equation Z = -(abs(x)+abs(y)), i.e. find all (x, y) values leading to the given Z value ? In my mind, Matplotlib won't do that automatically, you need to know a priori X and Y value to plot a 3D graph, in the same sense than tcaswell... :/

Comment: I don't think I need something too fancy. Let's go back to the OP's surface exemplified. Suppose we already have our X, Y, Z for drawing a surface (in a cartesian grid), also suppose we know that below Z = k we will get the undesired effect of planes cutting through empty spaces. In the OP's surface, if we set k to -0.5, all is solved if we can hide the drawing below this k. Is this doable in numpy/matplotlib ? Thanks for the patience, by the way.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. So I think it could be possible to do it with numpy:

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. So I think it could be possible to do it with numpy like this: 1) compute Z from X and Y in an extra range, 2) select in this (X Y Z) array only lines where Z in under the known threshold and 3) plot the data since matplotlib need only X, Y and Z array. I'll check that if you want, no problem (if you have patience too :) )

Comment: (Or maybe there is directly a cutoff function in matplotlib, but I don't know it...)

Comment: That is looking good. Maybe I can adapt it to other cases, would you care to complement your initial answer with this approach ?

Comment: This is done... But maybe should you change your question (or create a new one), because it's no more really a revolution plot... :)

Comment: Well, yes, but it was an adaptation to satisfy the question. I'm accepting this, thank you. I didn't test it yet, as I don't have the needed matplotlib version, but the plot looks good.

Comment: Ok, so don't hesitate to tell me if it works correctly when you'll try  it!

Comment: I just tried it and it looks nice, but I suspect there is some bug in plot_trisurf. I modified X and Y to linspace(-1, 1, 21) and modified the cut off to Z > -1, but the interpolation looks plain wrong. So I changed cut off to Z >= -1 and got, with some fluff, http://i.imgur.com/RYKOy.png .

As you can see, there are some triangles randomly orientated when compared to the others. If the "tri"plot comes from a Delaunay triangulation, then it seems the code is not handling, in a consistent way, the case of co-circularity of 4 points. But this is out of scope for this question.