# How to plot f(x,y,z) = t with matplotlib

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matplotlib

I have some datas that I need to display.

Because I use python, a quick search told me that matplotlib is the best solution.

I looked at the docs, but i can only find information on how to plot a function f(x,y) = t.

My problem is coming when you add a fourth dimension.

I have four arrays of data. The last dimension can be display with color informations.

I started doing this :
 `def f(x,y,z): #compute the function return t`

```
x : np.arange(1,9,1)
y : np.arange(1,9,1)
z : np.arange(1,9,1)
```

then I create my data structure containing the f(x,y,z) for all x,y,z

But then how should I display it ?

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Comment: Actually I think it is more related to a question I had myself, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432492/how-to-do-a-3d-revolution-plot-in-matplotlib and the comments. The accepted answer is problematic in part because of the interpolation implementation and also because, I believe, of matplotlib limitations.

Answer (score -1):

If the `t` is a given constant number, then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680525/plotting-implicit-equations-in-3d).

If the `t` is another parameter, then this question is actually that what the 4D world would look like. Let me know if you mean that.

Comment: I confirm: if t is also a variable, you are in the 4D world.. I'm working in computational fluid dynamics and I deal with this everyday: dedicated visualization software (like open source one Paraview) would give you more possibilities than matplotlib...