# Making surface plots in with matlotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

I am making a surface plot using python 3, using spyder. My plot doesn't seem to be coming out correctly however. Below is a screenshot of my view from the spyder terminal. The contour plot shows that the data is indeed coming out correctly. I am not sure why the contour plot is not. The surface plot also fails to save. All of the saved pngs are blank.
[image]

My code is below,

```
#Logistic regression data and link function.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
from matplotlib import cm

m= 800

#Define link function here
def g(z):
    g=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    return g


def loglikelihood(X,y,beta):
    h = g(X@beta)
    b=np.divide(h,(1-h))
    b=np.reshape(np.log(b),(m,1))
    y=np.reshape(y,(1,m))
    c= np.dot(y,b)
    d = np.sum(np.log(1-h))
    l=c+d
    return l

#For producing y data values given true paramters theta and number of covariates
def logit_data(n,p, theta):
    #Define parameters

    #1)Number of covariates
    p_i = p+1  #with intercept
    p_i=np.int(p_i)

    #2) m as correct data type
    n=np.int(n)

    #4)Specify parameter valueas to be estimated
    theta=np.reshape(theta, (p_i,1))

    #5)Define distribution from which covariate values are drawn i.i.d., and initiate data values
    X=np.zeros((n,p_i))
    X[:,0]=1    #intercept
    mean=0
    sigma=1

    X[:,1:]=np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(n,p))


    #6)Produce y values treating y as a Bernoulli variable with p=g(X*theta)
    r=np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
    r=np.reshape(r, (len(r),1))
    htrue=g(X.dot(theta))
    y=htrue-r
    y[y>=0]=1
    y[y<0]=0

    return X, y



p=2
theta = [0,2.5,4]

interval = 100
theta1try = np.linspace(0,5,interval)
theta2try = np.linspace(2,6,interval)

X,y = logit_data(m,p,theta)

A=np.zeros((interval,interval))

beta = [0,0,0]
for i in range(interval):
    for j in range(interval):
        beta[1] = theta1try[i]
        beta[2] = theta2try[j]
        A[i,j] = loglikelihood(X,y,beta)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

P,Q=np.meshgrid(theta1try,theta2try)
ax.plot_surface(theta1try,theta2try,A, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_title('Value of log likelihood function for varied parameter vectors theta')
ax.set_xlabel('theta 1')
ax.set_ylabel('theta 2')
ax.set_zlabel('log likelihood')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('loglikelihoodmesh1.png')

plt.contour(theta1try,theta2try,A)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Code doesn't run: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-75-4625a85aa764>", line 66, in <module>
    X,y = logit_data(n,p,theta)

NameError: name 'n' is not defined`   -   Can't you please create a [mcve]? Sth copy-pastable, which shows what you want to ask but is stripped off everything unneeded?

Comment: To me the 3D plot and the contour look consistent with each other. You probably want to explain more in detail where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Could you explai how they look consistent? The contour plot shows that I would expect a peak (which is what I expect on theoretical grounds). I was hoping I would get a plot like in this stack exchange post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432492/how-to-do-a-3d-revolution-plot-in-matplotlib/13494755  but I see no peak in mine. It just looks like a curved sheet! (I also fixed the one letter typo in the code)

Comment: Ah, I see. You probably want to plot `ax.plot_surface(P,Q,A, ...)` instead.